# Excluding values that don't fit the mask - Bitwise operations in mySQL

Tags: mysql, bitwise-operators

I need help solving a problem. I have a User with a Bitmask-Value, let's say 10010001.
Column name is value_1. In this column I have this values to compare with:

```
|--|----------|  
|id|   value_1|
|--|----------|
| 1| 00000001 |
| 2| 10010001 | 
| 3| 00000010 | 
| 4| 10000001 |
| 5| 10011001 |
|--|----------|
```

My query is this:

```
select value_1 from testdb
where b'10010001' & value_1;
```

My result is ID  1,2,4,5
This looks fine - but how can I exclude id 5 because the lowest 4th bit (counting from the right) is not in source?

Comment: what is the value_1 data type ???

Comment: bit 4 is set in `b'10010001`...

Comment: @YusufFidan Consider improving the title. Something to be more explicit, like maybe "Excluding values that don't fit the mask - bitwise operations in mySQL".

Comment: @liviriniu okay - it was my first question - I changed the title

Comment: @scaisEdge bit(8)

Comment: @Nick sorry for this confusion - source means b'10010001' in my query.

Comment: no worries, @YusufFidan, I had to tweak my own questions a lot, I just find that a good title really helps us here to find answers to what problems we may have. Your question was interesting, I really liked to resolve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the combined bits of value_1's value and mask do not result in a number that exceeds the mask as a number.

```
where (b'10010001' & value_1) and (cast((b'10010001' | value_1) as unsigned) <= cast(b'10010001' as unsigned))
```

Exceeding means that at least one bit is present in value_1's value but not in the mask (source).

Test it [here](https://paiza.io/projects/avqcvZyXxDlMkUL8mKCKdQ?language=mysql)

Answer (score 1):

assuming your value_1 data type is  string 
Try using a proper casting

```
    select value_1 from testdb
    where cast( '10010001' as unsigned )  & cast( value_1 as unsigned ) ;
```